# Store Procedure with param XML example in mysql without loop

Tags: mysql

I have example code query store procedure in sql server from internet like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_UpdateStudent` (@tblStudent  XML)
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO Student(StudentId,StudentName)
  SELECT    Student.value('(StudentId)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as StudentId,
    Student.value('(StudentName)[1]',  'nvarchar(100)') as StudentName
  FROM
  @tblStudent.nodes('/ArrayOfStudent/Student')AS TEMPTABLE(Student)
END
```

i am just wondering if is there any way to create this sp in mysql, because when i search it is dominant with sql server. i try to create it in mysql but got error in paramater XML. Here is my store procedure in mysql with param XML

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_test(IN param XML)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM master_course
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you *actually* using?

Comment: currently i am using mysql